# Determine ODS settings

Tags: sas

I am working inside a SAS macro application, and get the following warning before running a proc compare:

```
WARNING: No output destinations active.
```

Using the noprint option of proc compare does not suppress the warning.  Am pretty sure the only way to get rid of this warning is to open an ODS destination (eg `ods listing;`) before running the proc, however I do not want to disrupt existing settings as there may be different ODS states at run time.

Is there any way to determine the ODS state programmatically?  eg:

```
%let state=%sysfunc(getODSSTATE(listing)); /* for example */
ods listing;
proc compare base=x compare=y noprint; run;
ods listing &state; /* either %str(CLOSE) or %str() */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had thought `ODS SHOW;` would be a solution, but that tracks the select/exclude, not the open destination.

One solution might be to choose a destination that is unlikely to be open - an obscure tagset perhaps - and open that to a dummy file, then close it.  `ODS PREFERENCES;`also seems like a good compromise; it will open up whatever your default destination is, at least.

Honestly though, if you're writing a macro application, I would just leave the ODS alone; it should be up to the programmer using your macro to properly set up ODS ahead of time.

Comment: I'm not writing the application - am working within an existing one.  ODS SHOW might have worked, if it didn't throw an error if listing was closed..  ODS PREFERENCES is not viable, as I don't want to interfere with existing destinations.  In the end, after realising that ODS LISTING was switched OFF by default due to the presence of %stpbegin, I am simply switching it on and back off again after the procedure.  Am thinking this could be a bug (noprint should mean no need for ODS), will see what SAS support think about it!

Comment: I don't think NOPRINT technically means no ODS destinations.

Comment: Turns out this IS a defect on proc compare.. and that there is no easy way to remove the message without affecting the performance of the proc (which is primary concern obviously).  Being looked at though..

Comment: Good to know!  You might add an answer with the results from the SAS tech support discussion for future readers.