# Determine ODS STATE

Tags: sas

Has there been any movement on this subject in the past 10 years.

[Determine ODS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055974/determine-ods-settings/18060017#18060017)

I am searching for solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't that what SASHELP.VDEST is for?

```
proc sql ;
describe view sashelp.vdest;
describe table dictionary.destinations;
quit;

proc print data=sashelp.vdest; run;
```

Log

```
1698  proc sql ;
1699  describe view sashelp.vdest;
NOTE: SQL view SASHELP.VDEST is defined as:

        select *
          from DICTIONARY.DESTINATIONS;

1700  describe table dictionary.destinations;
NOTE: SQL table DICTIONARY.DESTINATIONS was created like:

create table DICTIONARY.DESTINATIONS
  (
   destination char(100) label='Destination',
   style char(32) label='Style'
  );

1701  quit;
```

Output:

```
 OBS    destination     style

   1      HTML         HTMLBlue
   2      LISTING      Listing
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.   I'm still learning.

Comment: Active named destinations such as `ODS HTML(ONE)` or `ODS PDF("Final Report")` will be delivered from the dictionary as `HTML(ONE)` or `PDF(Final Report)`